# JQuery Autocomplete passing an ID but displaying value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to display a value in the autocomplete field after selection but pass the id.  The relevant code is:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#Autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'towns.php',
    }); 
});  

$json[] = array(
    'label' => $towns["townName"],
    'value' => $towns["town_id"]
);
```

When I select the autocomplete label it defaults to the value.

Comment: is `$json[]=array(...` what is in the php file? did use use `json_encode()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$( "#Autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
            source: json_data,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                var selectedObj = ui.item;
                $(this).val(selectedObj.label);
                $(this).parent().find('.hidden').val(selectedObj.value);
              return false;
            }
   });
```